# Does disabling right click have any impact on security?

Tags: web-applications, security, banking

On a banking website or some other website, I saw that they have disabled right-click. Does disabling right click make the site any more secure in referance to client-side? Is it a good general practice?

Comment: Not really, it usually just bothers the user, who can bypass it anyway.

Comment: The server doesn't care if it is disabled or not.

Comment: No. It does not make website more secure.
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31229/does-disabling-right-click-have-any-impact-on-security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No is not good to disable the right click in website. For details  Click below

http://www.sitepoint.com/dont-disable-right-click/

Comment: it doesn't help with security but can sometimes make the site act more intuitively like a native app. For example, try right clicking somewhere in Google Docs. You actually get a context menu relevant to the webapp. However, it has the effect of making it annoying to get to your normal chrome/firefox extensions that build off context menu - some middle ground would be awesome

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make the website more secure, it's just that if you have right click enabled then:

1. The user can see the source code
2. The user can use Console to keep a track on what data is being loaded from what location
3. User can see your client side files (JS, HTML, CSS etc.)

But any user can easily bypass "Disable right click code" so that does not really help